# Conflict in the Sizeof Long

Tags: c, sizeof

I checked on the net it shows size of long to be 4 bytes . But when I print sizeof(long) in my laptop it prints 8 . Why is there a conflict in the values ? I am using this print statement

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(long));
```

Comment: No.  The C standard says long must be at LEAST as wide as an "int".  It does *NOT* specify exactly how wide it *MUST* be.  The width of "long" can - and *WILL* - vary from platform to platform.

Comment: I am trying to extract data from a raw file the size of long they have used is 4 . What should I do ?

Comment: @FoggyDay that is false, per the standard, int has to be at least 2 bytes while long has to be at least 4 bytes.

Comment: @Shivam Jadhav - you simply can't assume that sizeof(long) will be "4" on all compilers on all platforms. It won't - it can and will vary. As will "int" and "long long" types.  As the busybee said, if you *need* a fixed width of 4 bytes, then the solution is to `#include <stdint.h>` and use `int32_t` (instead of "long"): https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "conflict" you mean to see comes from the standard, which does not specify specific widths of the integer types. Different compilers use different widths.

But the *real* question you have is: "What should I do?"

The answer is to use the types provided by the standard for such purpose. Include "stdint.h" and use `int32_t` (or `uint32_t` for unsigned integers) for 4-byte integers.

Please get yourself a standard, and take the time to look in it. You don't need to read every line, though, just enough to know what to expect therein.